# PUG, the slash (/) disappear when renders to HTML

Tags: html, pug

In my script file

```
   const str = `<div style="background-image: url(upload` + "/" + `f3637455.jpeg)">`
```

In my pug file

```
div!= str
```

But when pug renders itself to HTML, the slash disappear like this.

```
<div><div style="background-image: url(upload f3637455.jpeg"></div>
```

How should I do

Comment: Try using 2 slashes, sometimes code can treat a slash as an escape character.

Comment: Are you passing str variable from server side(node) to view(pug)?

Comment: I used 2 slashes but it became 2 spaces. Lincoln
Yes, I am. Mr.Ratnadeep

Answer (score 1):

Try escape it with unicode code, for achieve it replace "/" for **"\u002F"**

Comment: const str = `<div style="background-image: url(upload\u002Ff3637455.jpeg)">`

result: <div style="background-image: url(upload f3637455.jpeg">

const str = `<div style="background-image: url(uploadescaped="\u002F"f3637455.jpeg)">`

result: <div style="background-image: url(uploadescaped="/"f3637455.jpeg)">

Comment: I don't programming in Pug spefically... But I think you could work with simple quotes, for example: <div style="background-image: url(uploadescaped='\u002F' + 'f3637455.jpeg')">. I hope can useful!